# Apache DBD with sqlite3

Tags: apache-httpd, selinux, sqlite

I'm trying to make apache load basic auth credentials from a sqlite3 database.

The configuration I've tried (and many other variations) is:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName git.example.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/git-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/git-access_log" common
    DocumentRoot "/usr/share/cgit/"
    DBDriver sqlite3
    DBDParams "/home/git/db.sqlite"
    DBDMin 1
    DBDKeep 2
    DBDMax 10
    DBDExptime 60

    <Directory "/usr/share/cgit/">
        AuthType Basic 
        AuthName Test 
        AuthBasicProvider dbd 
        Require valid-user 
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT pw AS password FROM cgit_passwords WHERE uid=%s" 
        AllowOverride None
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /cgit.css "/usr/share/cgit/cgit.css"
    Alias /cgit.png "/usr/share/cgit/cgit.png"
    Alias /favicon.ico "/usr/share/cgit/favicon.ico"
    #ScriptAlias / "/var/www/cgi-bin/cgit/"
    #Alias /cgit-data "/usr/share/cgit"
</VirtualHost>
```

However, apache complains that:

> [dbd:error] [pid 16673] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to sqlite3: unable to open database file

Which doesn't make sense. I've enabled a shell for the apache user, logged in with `su - apache`, and I can open and execute operations on the database `"/home/git/db.sqlite"`

Comment: Is this on a Linux system? On one with SELinux enabled?

Comment: Yes, selinux is enabled.

Comment: as another possibility: http://fredericiana.com/2014/11/29/sqlite-error-open-database-file/ -- indicates that the apache user would need to be able to write a file in /home/git

Comment: Apache user is able to create new files in /home/git and write to them.

Comment: Are there any related log entries in audit log (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`)?